# Is It Possible To Replicate Tab Stop Behaviour (or Even PageFooter Behaviour but in Regular Cell)

Tags: formatting, text, alignment

I am trying to insert a (text) cell into a notebook that replicates the behaviour of tab stops in MS Word, for example.  Put differently, I have two strings and I want the one string to align on the left side of a page and the other string to align on the right side of the page *but on the same line*.

I thought it may perhaps be possible using some version of:

```
Cell[
    TextData[{
            Cell["First String",TextAlignment->Left], " \t ",
            Cell["Second String",TextAlignment->Right]
    }], "Text"]
```

Of course, this doesn't work.  In fact, I have realised that I can't use regular menu formatting commands to create the effect I want in a cell (so that I could look at the raw expression and see how it is done).  Perhaps it can't be done?

**However** I do know, for example, that one can set the `PageFooters`/`PageHeaders` option in the stylesheet for a notebook and that this option is preset to accept a list like `{{ll,lc,lr},{rl,rc,rr}}` where the first list is for left-facing pages and the second for right-facing pages and the three elements in each list correspond to left alignment, center alignment and right alignment of text in the footer (essentially what I want to do in a regular cell).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could work for you:

```
Composition[
  CellPrint,
  Cell[#, "Text"] &,
  BoxData,
  ToBoxes,
  Grid[{{
      Pane[#, Alignment -> Left], 
      Pane[#2, Full, Alignment -> {Right, Center}]}}] &
  ][
    "Left",
    "Right"
   ]
```

> [image]